# Why Invalid RegistraitonID with GCM - working with phonegap for android?

Tags: cordova, google-cloud-messaging

I have done with the server side coding with deviceId, apiKey and senderId. May I know why I still get this "Invalid Registration" ??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the registration ID that is generated on the client side. It seems that registration id in the client side and server side do not match.

Here is the explanation from the [GCM page](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html).

> Check the formatting of the registration ID that you pass to the
>   server. Make sure it matches the registration ID the phone receives in
>   the com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION intent and that you're
>   not truncating it or adding additional characters.  Happens when error
>   code is InvalidRegistration.

Comment: Registration id is not generating neither in the emulator/nor in the device. It is reading as null.

Comment: Did you get exception on the client side? Check permissions in manifest file.For getting started use this page to check whether you do everything ok or not.http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html

Comment: Registration id is generated. When I check from server side it is giving response as "Invalid Registration" what could be the reason?

Comment: Registration id on the server side should match with the registration id generated on the client side. Check if they are same or not.

Comment: Registration ID client side and server side are same, but server response is "INVALID REGISTRATION". We are using .net program in server side. I am using the following format in server side :     string postData = "collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=108&delay_while_idle=1&data.message=" + value + "&data.time=" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "®istration_id=" + deviceId + ""; http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/434338/Android-GCM-Push-Notification   registrationid or device id?? what to mention in this??

Comment: as a device id you should set your registrationID generated on the client side. For the GoogleAppID you should set the API key that you get from google.Check this page to see how you get API key.http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html

Comment: Key for server apps (with IP locking) - This is I am mentioning as google application ID, sender ID as projectID and deviceID as Registrstion ID. Still response is "INVALID REGISTRATION"                             Is there any thing that I need to do with: code.google.com/apis/console-dashboard page:"A project ID is a unique, DNS-compatible label similar to a hostname that is used by certain services to locate your project and access its resources. A project ID is only required when a service you use depends on it."I don't have any project ID in this. What is the projectID there?

Comment: is it telling that this project ID is not mandatory until unless service depends on it??

Comment: If I mention my package name(as it is asking "DNS-compatible") as the projectID, will this be help full for me to get success message?

Comment: Did you got the solution? I have the same problem here.